# Would a filter that removes query parameters effect Site Search and UTM tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

In order to clean up the URL's in the Pages reports (all page URL's can have a ton of different query parameters that serve no purpose) I am thinking of creating a new view with a filter that removes all query parameters from page URL's (aka a filter that removes all text after a ?).

However, UTM tracking and Site Search appear as similar query parameters in the URL's;:

- Site Search is identified by the ?q=(search query) parameter (set up in admin)
- UTM tracking apperas as follows: example.com?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=test

My question is, if I create a filter that removes all URL parameters that start with a ? would that ruin my Site Search and UTM campaign tracking? Or are those things (the Site Search query and the campaign tracking) taken into account before filters are applied?

Comment: Since you can see campaign info in the realtime view this would take about one minute to test, so why don't you try and then answer your own question :-)

Comment: That totally slipped my mind. For those who are interested having filters that exclude all query parameters has no impact on either Site Search or UTM campaign tracking.